# Symmetry in the complex semisimple lie algebra - help to understand definition

Tags: root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

I got stucked in the definition of "symmetry" in the chapter of Lie Algebras to understand later the root systems. Well in the script they used the following definition:
Let $\alpha \in V\setminus \{0\}$. A symmetry with vector $\alpha$ is an element of $s \in GL(V)$ with $$s(v)=v-\alpha^*(v)\alpha$$
for all $v \in V$ with $\alpha^*(\alpha)=2$.
Now the book of Serre "Complex Semisimple Lie Algebra" gives us an other definition: 
Let $\alpha \in V\setminus \{0\}$. One defines a symmetry with vector $\alpha$ to be any automorphism $s$ of $V$ satisfying the following two conditions:

(i) $s(\alpha) = - \alpha$

(ii) The set $H$ of elements of $V$ fixed by $s$ is a hyperplane of $V$.

I know don't see the relation between these two definitions. Especially the second point in the second definition confuses me a lot. Also what can I understand under the expression $\alpha^*(\alpha)$?

Many thanks for some help.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these definitions capture the idea of "[reflection in the hyperplane perpendicular to $\alpha$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_through_a_hyperplane_in_n_dimensions)". Concretely, if $v \in V$ you can write $v = a\alpha + h$ where $h \perp \alpha$, and this reflection sends $v$ to $-a\alpha + h$. (In particular, it fixes everything in the hyperplane perpendicular to $\alpha$).

$\alpha^*$ refers to the linear map $V \to \mathbb{R}$ (or whatever field $V$ is a vector space over) sending $\alpha$ to 2 and sending everything perpendicular to $\alpha$ to 0, so $\ker \alpha^*$ is the hyperplane perpendicular to $\alpha$. The notation $\alpha^*(\alpha)$ just means evaluate the function $\alpha^*:V \to \mathbb{R}$ at $\alpha \in V$.

If $\alpha^*$ is such a map, you can check that $s(v) = v - \alpha^*(v)a$ really sends $a\alpha + h$ to $-a\alpha +h$ so it is the reflection described above.

In (ii), "The set $H$ of elements fixed by $s$" means $H=\{v \in V: s(v)=v\}$, and saying that this is a hyperplane means that $\dim H = \dim V - 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to understand, $\alpha$ is an element of the vector field and $\alpha*$ is a linear map. This map send everything perpendicular to $\alpha$ to $0$ (why is it? Per definition or I missed something?). Okay but I still don't see why I can write $v= a \alpha + h$ with $ h \perp \alpha$...

Comment: $\alpha \in V$, and $\alpha^* : V \to \mathbb{R}$ (or whatever), yes. If you want to define the reflection then you define $\alpha^*$ to vanish on everything perpendicular to $\alpha$. You can write $v = a\alpha + h$ because $H$ has codimension 1 and $\alpha \notin H$, so every element in $V$ can be written uniquely as $a\alpha + h$.